# How to define and read empty XML fields?

Tags: xml, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I'm using Jaspersoft studio to create label. I'm using an XML file along with an XMLDataAdapter. Here is an example of my XML file

```
<records>
  <record>
    <metadatas>
        <title>first title</title>
        <description>descriptions</description>
        <keywords />
        <!-- ... -->
    </metadatas>
  </record>
</records>
```

The problem here is that I want to access the keywords fields, which can be set in some case or not, but when I try to read fields in the data adapter they do not show up.

Is there a configuration to change or somethings to I can compile my jasperreport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no special setting you just not define your fields relative to the XPath query

In your example you probably like to loop on record so your XPath query will be

```
<queryString language="XPath">
    <![CDATA[/records/record]]>
</queryString>
```

To define a field that points to `keywords` you use the `fieldDescription`

```
<field name="keywords" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[metadatas/keywords]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
```

> The name is arbitrary, the class is the representation of value in java and the fieldDescription is relative path to your node related to your queryString

## JasperSoft Studio

In JasperSoft Studio this is achieved by first [defining your data adapter](https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jaspersoft-studio-user-guide/v611/creating-and-editing-data-adapters), then right clicking report node, and select "Dataset and Query". In the dialog select your data adapter and XPath, then write your XPath query and click fields you like to add as fields

[image: Dataset and Query]

## Full jrxml example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="XMLTest" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="b487729d-4510-4485-b838-19c491042208">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="XMLTest"/>
    <queryString language="XPath">
        <![CDATA[/records/record]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="title" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[metadatas/title]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="description" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[metadatas/description]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="keywords" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[metadatas/keywords]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="170" height="20" uuid="3ce3004b-8324-4f57-ba9f-77cdffc711da"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[title]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="170" y="0" width="170" height="20" uuid="6ee7c571-ecdc-45cc-b11d-600099121301"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[description]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="340" y="0" width="210" height="20" uuid="111fa52f-bc0b-4698-8ba9-a7af03988254"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[keywords]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="170" height="20" uuid="444010e8-18ce-4594-a1b1-ca3d120b091d"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{title}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="170" y="0" width="170" height="20" uuid="9a27a707-c5df-4905-ac21-e42b21c1d77c"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{description}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="340" y="0" width="210" height="20" uuid="1621de6d-7200-49aa-a0d4-56f64fec1b91"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{keywords}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

## Example datasource

```
<records>
  <record>
    <metadatas>
        <title>first title</title>
        <description>descriptions</description>
        <keywords />
    </metadatas>
  </record>
  <record>
    <metadatas>
        <title>second title</title>
        <description>descriptions 2</description>
        <keywords>test, hello</keywords>
    </metadatas>
  </record>
</records><records>
  <record>
    <metadatas>
        <title>first title</title>
        <description>descriptions</description>
        <keywords />
    </metadatas>
  </record>
  <record>
    <metadatas>
        <title>second title</title>
        <description>descriptions 2</description>
        <keywords>test, hello</keywords>
    </metadatas>
  </record>
</records>
```

## Output

[image: Result]

As you will se it will show `null` for nodes that do not have value, if you like to show empty text just set `isBlankWhenNull="true"` on the relative `textField`

Comment: pretty good answer, but my problem is that i only have one records at the time but i want to create a label for multiple records, and the current records does not have any keywords so the fields does not appear.

Comment: Then add it manually? Either as add field or directly in jrxml

Comment: Yea that's what i will do, i was just wondering if there was any other ways,

Comment: Thanks you very much !

Comment: If not present in xml there is no automatic way, but you can use IDE (selecting add field), your welcome